# How can I programatically set the default browser in Windows 10

Tags: c#, file-type

I want be able to change the default browser (and other associations) via a C# program similar to how browsers have a "Make Browser As Default" option.

I've tried changing HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice but Windows just detects tampering, even if I restore both the Hash and ProgId to a previous value. Seems Hash is unique, time based

Comment: Please stop messing with people computer. Browser selection is a choice of the user.

Comment: Tell that to Microsoft. My defaults are Chrome, Paint NET, Daum Player but they still keep asking every few months How Should We Open this File, Recommended: Edge, Paint, Video

Comment: @Phil1970 what if he/she is writing a program to allow the user to change their default browser?

Answer (score 2):

There are various articles on using DISM to change the default browser for Windows 10 (e.g.  From: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1812853-export-xml-with-dism-then-import-with-powershell  ). Essentially this involves replacing a string in the file "C:\Windows\System32\OEMDefaultAssociations.xml" that contains the original string from Microsoft  (e.g. default browser 'Edge') with another string (e.g with IE). You can do the same thing in C#, here I did it with PowerShell. I know this works for any new user profiles that are created on the computer after this change is made. The file "OEMDefaultAssociations.xml" acts like a configuration file for new profiles.

```
#'  IE_ratherThan_Edge_MakeDefaultForNewUserProfiles_inWin10.ps1
#' From: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1812853-export-xml-with-dism-then-import-with-powershell
#'========================================================
#' This is good for Win10 Build 1709 and 1803

#'Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope LocalMachine

$file_OriginalWithEdge = "C:\Windows\System32\OEMDefaultAssociations.xml" 
$file_CopyToKeepInCase = "C:\Windows\System32\OEMDefaultAssociations_ORIG_Edge_BEFORE_replacingWithIE.xml"
$file_Modified_BrowserIE = "C:\Windows\System32\OEMDefaultAssociations_Modified_with_IEratherThanEdge.xml" 

#' 1] Copy and rename the file
Copy-Item $file_OriginalWithEdge -Destination $file_CopyToKeepInCase


$stringForEdge_1 = '<Association Identifier=".htm" ProgId="AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX6k1pws1pa7jjhchyzw9jce3e6hg6vn8d" />'
$stringForIE_1 = '<Association Identifier=".htm" ProgId="htmlfile" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9" />'

$stringForEdge_2 = '<Association Identifier=".html" ProgId="AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX6k1pws1pa7jjhchyzw9jce3e6hg6vn8d" />'
$stringForIE_2 = '<Association Identifier=".html" ProgId="htmlfile" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX4hxtad77fbk3jkkeerkrm0ze94wjf3s9" />'

$stringForEdge_3 = '<Association Identifier="http" ProgId="AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppXehk712w0hx4w5b8k25kg808a9h84jamg" />'
$stringForIE_3 = '<Association Identifier="http" ProgId="IE.HTTP" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppXq0fevzme2pys62n3e0fbqa7peapykr8v" />'

$stringForEdge_4 = '<Association Identifier="https" ProgId="AppX90nv6nhay5n6a98fnetv7tpk64pp35es" ApplicationName="Microsoft Edge" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppXz8ws88f5y0y5nyrw1b3pj7xtm779tj2t" />'
$stringForIE_4 = '<Association Identifier="https" ProgId="IE.HTTPS" ApplicationName="Internet Explorer" ApplyOnUpgrade="true" OverwriteIfProgIdIs="AppX90nv6nhay5n6a98fnetv7tpk64pp35es" />'



#' 2] Replace the string
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($file_OriginalWithEdge).Replace($stringForEdge_1,$stringForIE_1).Replace($stringForEdge_2,$stringForIE_2).Replace($stringForEdge_3,$stringForIE_3).Replace($stringForEdge_4,$stringForIE_4)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText($file_Modified_BrowserIE, $content)

#' 3] Delete the original File
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file_OriginalWithEdge

#' 4] Copy the modified file to the name of the original file
Copy-Item $file_Modified_BrowserIE -Destination $file_OriginalWithEdge
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Microsoft is trying to prevent the ability to *programmatically* change the default web browser, by not disclosing the hash algorithm that is used to create the `Hash` value that is required to accompany and match the values in the relevant registry keys.

However, a *third-party utility*, `SetDefaultBrowser.exe`, has figured out this algorithm, and therefore allows fully automated changes to the user's default web browsers:

- For background information and a download link, see [this blog post](https://kolbi.cz/blog/2017/11/10/setdefaultbrowser-set-the-default-browser-per-user-on-windows-10-and-server-2016-build-1607/).

  - Note: There is an *obsolete* warning in the linked blog post about needing a *portable* browser installation - it can safely be ignored.
- Alternatively, if you have [Chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/setdefaultbrowser) installed, you can install [`SetDefaultBrowser.exe`](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/setdefaultbrowser) as follows:

  ```
  choco install setdefaultbrowser -y
  ```

Comment: @DavidMaze, the essential part of the linked post _is_ in the answer. The value of this answer is in providing a high-level explanation of why a solution isn't possible unless you have insider knowledge, and in _pointing to a downloadable utility_ (plus extended background information) that wraps this insider knowledge. I've since learned that the utility is also downloadable via Chocolatey, so I've added another download link.